# Check if Value comes exactly 2 times in given selections

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I need to check that in the given selections, my value should be there only 2 times.

]Image showing it all?

[image]

```
Item1   Item2   Item3   Item4

 22       24       3      15

 26       21      18      19

 18        5       4       6

 19       23      30      12

 16        8      27      11

 15        2      28      17

  3       26      13      10

 24       14       1      25

 12        6      29      28

  5       17      16      30

 27        1       9       7

  4       25      21       7

 23       10       8      20

 29       9       22      20

 11       13       2      14
```

Since every number is there only 2 times in this selection. But what if this is not like that.

How can I check if this is not 2 times?

Comment: You mean to say that you want to get the count of each value,,,? For example how many times 22 occurs in 4 Columns !

Comment: Or you want to highlight values occurs once only ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of the numbers in your table using the SEQUENCE function, then use COUNTIF to count the occurrences of each number in the table and then check if that number is not equal to 2.

Convert your data to a Table. Put your cursor in the data and press Ctrl+T. I've named the table YourTable in the screenshot below.

[image]

The formula for the number column (F) is:

```
=SEQUENCE(MAX(YourTable)-MIN(YourTable)+1,1)
```

It just means, give me a 1 column list of the numbers between the smallest and largest number in your table.

Occurrences:

```
=COUNTIF(YourTable,$F2)
```

It means 'count the times the number in column F appears in YourTable'.

is_ok:

```
=G2=2
```

Probably don't need to explain that one!

You could combine occurrences and is_ok, of course, but I figured it's probably useful to see how many occurrences there are. Anyway, if you wanted to combine:

```
=COUNTIF(YourTable,$F2)=2
```